# How do you print multiline exec output in golang

Tags: go, exec

I'm trying to write a simple golang program that lists the files in a directory. Whenever my shell command yields multiple lines, it registers in Go as an array

For example, when i try the following:

```
import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "fmt"
)
func main (){

    out,err := exec.Command("ls").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(out)

}
```

I end up with the output `[101 108 105 109 115 116 97 116 115 46 105 109 108 10 101 110 118 10 115 99 114 97 116 99 104 10 115 114 99 10]`

I feel like this is a common thing to do but wasn't able to find it on here anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return type of the first value from `Output` is `[]byte`. `fmt.Println` is displaying the numeric values of each slice element.

To show the desired result of the output of the command, you can either convert the byte slice to a string or use a format string with the `%s` verb:

```
fmt.Println(string(out))
```

Or:

```
fmt.Printf("%s\n", out)
```